# Как из мапы по ключам удалить несколько значений в цикле? Этот код не работает

Tags: java, map

```
private void deleteCars() {
        for (String numberCar : cars.keySet()) {
            if (getCar(numberCar).isFlRemoved())
                cars.remove(numberCar);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Нужна помощь начинающему программисту.... Кто чем может   помогите

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться методом `java.util.Collection::removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`, взяв предварительно из нужной `map` множество записей, либо множество ключей:

```
cars.keySet().removeIf(number -> getCar(number).flRemoved);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя модифицировать список во время итерации по нему.
Сохрани ключи в отдельный список и итерируя по нему удаляй из мапы.

Comment: Спасибо.... теперь буду знать

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(cars.keySet());
    for (String numberCar : keys) {
        if (getCar(numberCar).isFlRemoved())
            cars.remove(numberCar);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо... сработало